# Does witch hunter rage power work on alchemists?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist, barbarian

For a [barbarian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian) with the [witch hunter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/witch-hunter-ex) [rage power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers), would an [alchemist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist) count as a viable target for the extra damage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Extracts aren't spells, but an alchemist may have spell-level abilities

The barbarian rage power [witch hunter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/witch-hunter-ex) says

> While raging, the barbarian gains a +1 bonus on damage rolls against creatures possessing spells or spell-like abilities. This damage bonus increases by +1 for every four levels the barbarian has obtained.

The alchemist's class feature [alchemy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Alchemy-Su-) says, in part, that

> Although the alchemist doesn't actually cast spells, he does have a formulae list that determines what extracts he can create. An alchemist can utilize spell-trigger items if the spell appears on his formulae list, but not spell-completion items (unless he uses Use Magic Device to do so).

Several other places in the description of the class feature alchemy clarify that the ability to prepare and employ extracts is *not* the same thing as being able to prepare and cast spells. An alchemist possesses no *spells* through the class feature alchemy, only extracts.

However, an alchemist that selects an appropriate alchemist's [discovery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Discovery-Su-) may gain one or more spell-like abilities, such as an alchemist under the effect of its [cognatogen](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/cognatogen-su) that also picked the discovery [intuitive understanding](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/intuitive-understanding-sp). Such an affected alchemist *would* be dealt extra damage by a raging barbarian with the rage power witch hunter.

Comment: Huh, turns out the site contradicts itself somewhat. If you use the link which lists all rage powers, it states that only spellcasters are affected, while the page you linked says all creatures with spells or spell-like abilities would be affected. This would change my answer somewhat.

Comment: @Joninean Pathfinder has resisted defining such things, but 3.5 explicitly calls the short descriptions in the list "secondary" to the full descriptions for each one, so the latter win.

Comment: So in general the alchemist would not, but there are specific abilities that can be chosen which would. Thats what I needed to know, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The alchemist gains no caster levels, which means he is no caster, hence wouldn't be a viable target for the Witch Hunter Rage Power.

---

EDIT: Turns out all creatures that can cast spells or use spell-like abilities can be affected, which means my answer is not completely correct.

Comment: There are several races which grant racial spells without having caster levels. So I need a greater clarification than that.